# datagridView e.columnindex getting trouble

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2  buttons on datagridview EDIT & DELETE. I check on cellContentClick event that e.columnIndex.Once I click on EDIT button it works properly, and then click on DELETE button then I got e.columnIndex is 0.

Here my code

```
private void datagridview.CellContentClick(object sender, Datagridviewcelleventargs e)
{
  int col= e.columnIndex
  if (col==6)
    {
          //code for EDIT
    }
    if (col==7)
    {
          //code for DELETE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of lack of information this is my guess :)

I am assume that button columns was added after `DataSource` was set
And index of that columns became 6 and 7 (last columns after generated columns)

After pressing "Edit" button you updating some values
and updating `DataGridView` by set `DataSource` to the new data - this is an issue in your case

When you set `DataSource` second time, then `DataGridView` remove all generated columns and generate columns again based on the new datasource
Problem happened when `DataGridView` remove generated columns, then button columns, added by you, will not be removed and logically their index become 0 and 1

Solution will be comparing columns by their `Name`

When creating button columns add unique names for them

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn editcolumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
editcolumn.Name = "myDatagridviewEditColumn";
```

Then use names for comparing

```
private void datagridview.CellContentClick(object sender, Datagridviewcelleventargs e)
{
    If(e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    string columnName = this.YourDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (columnName.Equals("myDatagridviewEditColumn") == true)
    {
        //code for EDIT
    }
    if (columnName.Equals("myDatagridviewDeleteColumn") == true)
    {
        //code for DELETE
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From description it is not clear, what is the goal of listening the **CellContentClick** event, and on what manipulations you want to track the selected column index.

May be the **CurrentCellChanged** event will be more suitable in your case?

And i recommend you to use the **switch** statement for your purpose, to avoid numerous **if** blocks, like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = sender as DataGridView;
    if (gridView == null || gridView.CurrentCell == null) { return; }

    switch (gridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case 6:
            // edit
            break;
        case 7:
            // delete code
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Did not get (e.columnIndex) on currentCellChange event